# Published Getter and Setter in Dart

Tags: dart, polymer, setter, getter, dart-polymer

I've got two Custom Elements. The first (`wrap-elem`) is just a Wrapper around the second one (`two-inputs`) and the second one contains two input elements and therefore got two values.

`wrap-elem` has an attribute `@published value`, which is bound to the second element via two-way-databinding.
`<two-inputs value="{{value}}"/>`

`two-inputs` does have the two attributes `@published startValue` and `@published endValue` which are bound to input elements. And additionally I have a getter and a setter for value. `set value(val)` and `get value`. These two set the values of the attribute and return it as a single value (List).

My problem is, that the two-way-databinding in the first element `wrap-elem` does not access the getter and setter of value. Making setter and getter @published did not work.

I also tried using an attribute `@published value` in `two-inputs`, and override setter and getter, but this just didnt work...

So is there a way to make this binding, with setter and getter work?

Comment: Can you please add some code which allows to reproduce the problem? Interpreting prosa is error prone and often ambiuous.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Jqz9yuqa

Comment: This answer should provide what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/28345788/217408

Comment: My setter still does not get called by the two way data binding

Comment: Can you please update the pastebin or even better publish a GitHub repo containing a complete minimal runnable example which allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I got it to work after testing some stuff, since my case is a little bit more complicated than the example I described. But after all your comment was the answer. If you'd post it as answer, I'd accept it ;)